# How to remove the number of last items in the array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider i'm having dynamic array where my items keeps on increment each second.
So i want to remove the last 30 items in the  array when array reaches to 60  and keeps the rest in. That is i want to maintain only 30 items in array and remove the older items.

```
array=[1,2,3,4...........60] //Remove last 30 and show new 30 items
array=[21,22,23...30]
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this. My [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/6q7pnh4v/25/)

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't have any idea on this.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Array.slice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice . However, please, share your attempt to solve the issue.

Comment: You expected output is incorrect if we remove the last 30 elements

Comment: Please share the code that you use to create the array too.

Comment: careful with slice since you have to replace the array which changes the ref. Array::shift or a loop is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4....,60];

function arr_modify(arr,removeLength){
  if(arr.length == 60){
    arr.splice(0,removeLength)
  }
 return arr;
}

var modified_array = arr_modify(arr,30);
console.log(modified_array);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: this works but its doesn't remove older items. it keeps remove newly added

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to drop elements after the 30th

```
array.length=30;
```

If you want to drop all but the last 30

```
array.splice(0, array.length - 30);
```

here's a demo of both (using 10 instead of 30 for readability of output)

```js
const array = Array.from({length:60}, (_, i) => i);
array.length = 10;
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

const array2 = Array.from({length:60}, (_, i) => i);
array2.splice(0, array2.length - 10);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep last N of items use this code:

```js
let numberOfItemsToRemain = 5;
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let size = array.length;
array = array.splice(size-numberOfItemsToRemain, size);

console.log(array);
```

If you want to keep first N of items, use this code:

```js
let numberOfItemsToRemain = 5;
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
array = array.splice(0, numberOfItemsToRemain);

console.log(array);
```

*Edit numberOfItemsToRemain to 30 in your case.

Comment: You are not checking for the maximum length or the array.

Comment: I only wrote general solution for keeping first or last N items in array.